# C# Action syntax

Tags: c#

I have two methods like this:

```
public void ExecuteA()
{
    Write();
    // A specific work
    Clear();
}

public void ExecuteB()
{
    Write();
    // B specific work
    Clear();
}
```

I want to extract the `Write()` and `Clear()` methods to a new method (Action) to have something like this:

```
public ASpecificWork()
{
    // do A work
}

public BSpecificWork()
{
    // do B work
}

Execute(BSpecificWork);
Execute(ASpecificWork);
```

The `Write()` and `Clear()` will be defined in `Execute()` just one time.
What's the right syntax to do so?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
public void Execute(Action action)
{
    Write();
    action();
    Clear();
}
```

Comment: +1 although I would prefer letting A and B implement an interface.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - They are methods, not types, but yes, if they were in different types, that would be a better OOP approach.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
public ASpecificWork()
{
    // do A work
}

public BSpecificWork()
{
    // do B work
}

public void Execute(Action action)
{  
    Write();
    action();
    Clear();
}

Execute(BSpecificWork);
Execute(ASpecificWork);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Execute` should takes `Action` parameters and should contain `Write()`, `action()`, `Clear()` methods.

```
public void Execute(Action action)
{
    Write();
    action();
    Clear();
}
```